# How canI aggregate and group in two columns?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, group-by

```
   Name          age   gender
competition1      3      0
competition1      3      1
competition1      2      0
competition1      2      1
competition2      3      0
competition2      3      1
competition3      1      0
```

I want to query in this table that convert in below table.

```
     Name          Array of ages   Array of gender
'competition1',      {'3','2'}       {'0','1'}
'competition2',      {'3'}       {'0','1'}
'competition3',      {'1'}           {'0'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by `name`, and use `array_agg(distinct ...)` to generate arrays without duplicates. Note that you can also order the values in the arrays as needed:

```
select 
    name, 
    array_agg(distinct age order by age desc) ages, 
    array_agg(distinct gender order by gender) genders
from mytable
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_agg

```
 SELECT name, array_agg(age), array_agg(gender)
 FROM data_table
 GROUP BY name
```